# XML <!ENTITY e SYSTEM "/path/to/file"> does not work with PHP SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

```
<?php

$str = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc [
    <!ENTITY e SYSTEM "/tmp/exp">
]>
<tag>&e;</tag>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);

echo $xml;

?>
```

This should print out the contents of `/tmp/exp` but does not and I don't understand why, even when I run the script with `sudo` or change the `/tmp/exp` file permissions to `777`.

Comment: Try passing `LIBXML_NOENT` as the second argument to the constructor: https://3v4l.org/nTvDp

Comment: @ChrisHaas Before recommending switching on that option, you should understand why it's not on by default: it has been implicated in many security vulnerabilities, so needs to be used with care.

Comment: @IMSoP, I 100% agree, but it also seems like that might be what the OP is going for.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Not necessarily; obviously, the example in my answer is an unrealistically strict filter, but the key is that you can have a whitelist of where entities should be loadable from - e.g. there's unlikely to be a legitimate use for loading  `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading of external entities is disabled by default, because it can lead to [various security vulnerabilities](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing).

To safely enable it, you need to [register a custom entity loader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-external-entity-loader.php), which can check for expected entity paths and decide whether to load them. For instance, you might allow any file in a particular directory, but not elsewhere on disk - you probably don't need to allow a reference to system files like `/etc/passwd`. Or, you might map the path provided to a completely different location on your system.

You then also need to provide [the `LIBXML_NOENT` option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) to tell the parser to expand the entities via your handler.

For instance:

```
libxml_set_external_entity_loader(function($public, $system, $context) {
    if ($system === '/tmp/exp') {
        return fopen('/tmp/exp', 'r');
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
});
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str, LIBXML_NOENT);
```